# Show Variations in checkout Page

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a problem with Product Variation Description on checkout page it show only the first letter

on other pages it is working just fine

this is the code on cart-item-data.php

```
<dt class="variation-<?php echo sanitize_html_class( $data['key'] ); ?>">
<?
php echo wp_kses_post( $data['key'] ); ?>:</dt>
<dd class="variation-<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 
  $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $data['display'] ) 
 ); ?></dd>
```

thanks